# Blank png when canvas is saved toDataURL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am saving my canvas as an url base64 with the function toDataURL. However I get a full blank image when I want to use it after. I think it is a problem of saving the canvas when it is not fully loaded or something...

Here is my fiddle, I would like to be sure that my variable dataURL is the image represented in the canvas2

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/acbo6m6o/8/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10400072_76198580294_2746326_n.jpg?oh=b8cc93c35d6badfffb65ab5c9cbfce28&oe=5941AAB6";
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "https://icc-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/photo/2017/01/31/f3a228a9-30ca-453e-99c5-ee6150c714a5/Facebook_Logo.png";
img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    ctx.arc(150, 150, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx2.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 35, 60, 230, 230);
    ctx2.drawImage(img2, 200, 60, 75, 75);
}, true);

var dataURL = canvas2.toDataURL();
```

When I put the toDataURL in addeventListener I got undefined variable.

Comment: Should you not put `var dataURL = canvas2.toDataURL();` inside the onload event. That way the image will be rendered to the canvas rather than being blank.

Comment: I got something undefined : http://jsfiddle.net/acbo6m6o/9/

Comment: Because the image has not loaded yet. any code outside the onload event runs before the image has loaded. You need to move the ealert into the event after the toDataURL line

Comment: alert doesn't show :/

Comment: That is because the canvas is tainted and toDataURL is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like the following :

** ***note :*** *your images must've to be stored in your local server or a site that supports cross-origin (CORS) requests.*

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext("2d");
var ctx3 = document.getElementById('canvas3').getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10400072_76198580294_2746326_n.jpg?oh=b8cc93c35d6badfffb65ab5c9cbfce28&oe=5941AAB6";
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "https://icc-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/photo/2017/01/31/f3a228a9-30ca-453e-99c5-ee6150c714a5/Facebook_Logo.png";
img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    ctx.arc(150, 150, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx2.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 35, 60, 230, 230);
    ctx2.drawImage(img2, 200, 60, 75, 75);
    var dataURL = new Image();
    dataURL.src = ctx2.canvas.toDataURL();
    ctx3.drawImage(dataURL, 0, 0);
}, true);
```

```css
#canvas2 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
#canvas3 {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas2"></canvas>
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas3"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I really need to have a url of the image because I can only display an icon of a marker with a url. I can't use element of html...

Comment: @DionysoSong but even if you save the image using toDataURL, its gonna save the entire canvas as image not just the icon.

Comment: yes I want the entire image : the photo + the logo ^^

Comment: then why not draw the entire canvas using drawImage(). its the same thing as toDataURL

Comment: I am using google maps, for adding an icon for a marker I have a parameter like this : map.addMarker({ 'icon': 'img/Facebook-Logo.png' ... }); and I can't use a canvas and show it there.